Conda update flips between two versions of the same package from the same channel
This is the continuation of my previous question.
Now, with both channel_priority: flexible and channel_priority: strict,
every conda update -n base --all flips between
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  libarchive                               3.7.2-h313118b_1 --> 3.7.4-haf234dc_0
  zstd                                     1.5.5-h12be248_0 --> 1.5.6-h0ea2cb4_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  zstandard                          0.22.0-py311he5d195f_0 --> 0.19.0-py311ha68e1ae_0

and
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  zstandard                          0.19.0-py311ha68e1ae_0 --> 0.22.0-py311he5d195f_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  libarchive                               3.7.4-haf234dc_0 --> 3.7.2-h313118b_1
  zstd                                     1.5.6-h0ea2cb4_0 --> 1.5.5-h12be248_0

and the corresponding  conda list -n base --show-channel-urls are
libarchive                3.7.2                h313118b_1    XXX
zstandard                 0.22.0          py311he5d195f_0    XXX
zstd                      1.5.5                h12be248_0    XXX

and
libarchive                3.7.4                haf234dc_0    XXX
zstandard                 0.19.0          py311ha68e1ae_0    XXX
zstd                      1.5.6                h0ea2cb4_0    XXX

where XXX is the exact same (internal/corp) channel (which I do not cotrol).
What am I doing wrong? How do I avoid this?
Is this a bug in conda 24.5.0 or in the configuration of the XXX channel?
PS. Reported

What version of conda are you using?  conda -V

@James: conda 24.5.0

I cannot fully replicate the behavior that you are experiencing, so your mileage may vary with this solution.  Conda has a config feature that allows you to pin package specs.  This feature is still in beta according to the conda docs, so it may change in the future.
First add the package pinning to your conda config:
conda config --append pinned_packages "zstandard>=0.22.0"

Then install the newest version of zstandard and downgrade the other two packages.
conda install zstandard==0.22.0 libarchive==3.7.2 zstd==1.5.5

Finally check the upgrade again:
conda update -n base --all


Thank you for coming to my rescue again! Your recommendation means that every time conda goes into such a loop, I will have to add something to the config. This might be a viable work-around, but not a fix. So, is the bug in conda or in the channel?

Also, why did you chose zstandard==0.22.0 libarchive==3.7.2 zstd==1.5.5 instead of zstandard==0.19.0 libarchive==3.7.4 zstd==1.5.6?

I am not sure where the bug is coming from, but it is worth an issue on the Github page.  I choose the higher zstandard package because it is 3 minor versions up, as opposed to only increased patch versions for libarchive and zstd.

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/13945
